# Laravel 4: manipulating ajax data through controller

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel-4

I'm new at Laravel and ajax. I'm trying to get the data from a form via ajax and calling a method in the controller via that same ajax. The method in the controller searches the database and then returns a json response that gets handled by ajax(that last part I'm still thinking about, I haven't really done it yet).
Let me show you what I have now:

Routes.php:

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@getIndex');
Route::post('/', 'HomeController@postIndex');
```

HomeController:

```
public function getIndex()
{
    return View::make('index');
}

public function postIndex()
{
    $match = Input::get('search');
    $results = Customers::where('name', 'like', '%'.$match.'%')->get(); 
    return Response::json(array('results' => $results));
}
```

And my index.blade.php View :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form#find').submit(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url : 'CustomerSearch/Public',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: $('form#find').serialize(),           
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

and the form:

```
    {{ Form::open(array('url' => '', 'method' => 'POST', 'id' => 'find')) }}
    {{ Form::text('search', '', array('class' => 'search-query', 'placeholder' => 'Search')) }}
    {{ Form::submit('Submit', array('class' => 'btn btn-info')) }}
    {{ Form::close() }}
```

So I should be getting the data from the form then sending it to the "postindex" method in the controller so it gets processed and then sent back, right? Except I get the error     "Controller method [index] not found." when I don't actually call any index method since they are both named differently.
I'm new at this so sorry if it's not clear.

UPDATE:
Like I said in the commentaries, I found out combining the route into a route::controller got rid of my previous problem but unfortunately I'm still unable to get the ajax to send data to my controller. I get no errors, but the ajax doesn't load anything to the controller. Any idea what might be wrong with my ajax?:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form#find').submit(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url : '{{URL::to('/')}}',
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { search: $('.search-query').val() },
            success: function(info){
                 console.log(info);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: I figured it out myself, it was a pretty stupid question now that I know the answer !
For those this might help: there's a restful controller syntax in the documentation of laravel here: http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#restful-controllers

Basically I needed to change the routes.php to:

    Route::controller('/', 'HomeController');

Comment: That is half true.  You should be able to route to specific controller actions like you show ("Route::get('/', 'HomeController@getIndex');").  Something else may be going on here.

Answer (score 0):

Just use in your controller:

```
return json_encode(array('key' => 'val'));
```

For the input of data, I moved to a JQuery plugin that works nicely for me. [Follow this link](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/).
This is how a function looks like:

```
function someName(){
    // A plugin is used for this function
    $('#form_id').ajaxForm({
        url: '/',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response){
            alert(response.key);
        }
    });
}
```

and the corresponding form:

```
<form id="form_id">
    <!-- Put your fields here -->
    <input type="submit" onclick="someName()">
</form>
```

I would suggest you use this method, which may depend on the plugin but is the simplest. Of course, you could use the `.submit()` statement instead of binding it to the onclick event

Comment: Thanks for your response ! I like the jquery plugin but I still can't seem to get to work unfortunately. If add console.log's everywhere I can, I can see the trouble is when I try to send the data. It looks like it can't go to my postIndex method of my controller. Do you think it has something to do with my routes.php or something else?